# What is "The Hunt Is On!" interaction between Rengar and Kha' Zix?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've seen numerous mentions about the interaction of Rengar and Kha'Zix, but I have not seen any tested or official statements regarding it. From what I understand, it comes about when Rengar or Kha' Zix gets a kill on the other champion. The victor receives some sort of buff, but I'm unclear on how to activate the event or what the buff is exactly.

Does anyone have any official/tested information?

Comment: I saw this for the first time in blind pick normals today... which made me wonder: what happens if Kha'Zix and Rengar are both on both teams?

Comment: @ChrisPhillips That might be a good question to ask yourself, I know I'd be interested in the answer.

Comment: Good point. I was going quick and didn't have time to write it up at the time. I've opened a new question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89809/how-does-the-hunt-is-on-work-if-khazix-and-rengar-are-on-both-teams

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The gaining of the "Hunt is on" buff is apparently somewhat random. There are two requirements for the buff to come up. 1) Rengar must have the Bonetooth Necklace item, and 2) Kha'zix must have used 3 evolution points (requires him be at least level 16). The exact timing that the buff can start is currently unknown, if it even exists.

If Rengar kills or gets an assist on Kha'zix: Rengar's Bonetooth Necklace will be replaced with the Head of Kha'zix, and will gain a short buff called "Victory!" which as some extra flavor text. The Head of Kha'zix has the same stats as a fully stacked Bonetooth Necklace (regardless of how many stacks it had previously it will be fully stacked as the Head of Kha'zix item) and the stacks won't be lost upon death.

If Kha'zix kills or gets an assist on Rengar: Kha'zix will gain an extra Evolution Point, and gain the "Victory!" buff with some flavor text.

Source:

Comment: Just for clarification, its not random, both champions have to have met the requirement for the "quest" to start. Kha-Zix has to be at level 16 and Rengar has to have the Bonetooth Necklace.

Comment: Is it just me or is the hidden passives getting more and more game changing?

Comment: It's not just you.  Kha'zix's hidden in this case isn't that bad, but Rengar's is game breaking if it occurs (assuming this is accurate).

Comment: @Jeff I am not sure how Rengar's necklace works but I can assume that if he has no stacks by 16 then he is pretty bad so if he happens to pickup the kill and get the stacks it won't mean much since he has no items. And if he did have a lot of stacks becasue he was doing well it once again wouldn't do much.

Comment: @Emerica A Bonetooth Necklace imparts so many buffs at full stacks that it can make a bad Rengar average, an average Rengar great, and a great Rengar unstoppable.  Yes, in the extreme cases of a terrible or a fantastic Rengar, the difference might not be as noticeable because the game is already (mostly) won or lost by that point, but in the average case in the middle of the bell curve this is enough to greatly swing the game in the team's favor.  That's why it's game-breaking; one kill that triggers a hidden passive shouldn't be the crux of who wins or loses.

Comment: I don't know if you can really consider it a hidden passive. There is a buff at least that tells you something will happen, while Leona's hidden passive that she does less damage to champions wearing sunglasses is truly hidden. I do agree this is a big change compared to past champion interactions, and it may end up being too strong of one.

Comment: Leonas passive also is a negligible amount of damage. But regaurdless this seems to me like just a game mechanic. A counter is a counter.

Comment: and to be fair, Kha'Zix is (thus far) proving to be a rather terrible champion. So far he seems to be another Syndra-esque champ, but then again, he's only been released for a few days. (and therefore won't often be on the enemy team when there's a Rengar)

Comment: Getting a Kha'Zix kill is a situational answer to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/82302 for Rengars now. Also, note that assists are enough - so a much weaker champ can get in 1 hit, run and leave it to team mates to finish off the enemy Rengar/KZ

Comment: Has this event been confirmed yet?

Comment: I think they made something cool with this and it would be funnier if there was more interactions like this : It could complexify the picks ans counter picks and introduce some new strategies about countering a champion with his nemesis. The only bad thing here is that the decision of activating this passive is made by Rengar cause if he saws that the Kah'Zix became too strong he can stop the activation by selling his necklace in the other hand not reaching the level 16 is much hardier :-D