# Does a Non-Rengar-Associated Pentakill give Kha'zix a fourth evolution point or not?

Tags: league-of-legends

Apparently it is confirmed that it used to, however there is a deal of talk that it no longer works. Whats the deal? Did riot hotfix this? Was it a bug or an intended mechanic?

Comment: I've never heard of this...

Comment: @Shykin it was listed on the wiki, and several other websites (mobafire for example) for some time.

Comment: It's pretty interesting, I hope it's a feature not a bug, I'd like it to stay

Comment: @Ender links to sources?

Comment: Nop it doesn't the only way to have a fourth evolution point is : http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86059/what-is-the-hunt-is-on-interaction-between-rengar-and-kha-zix

Comment: @brian what form of source are you requesing? you already linked to a video proof of it occuring

Comment: @Ender I was mainly asking so I didn't link something that you used as a basis for asking the question

Comment: I have seen nothing "confirm" that the effect used to exist other than people claiming it did. No videos of a penta (without a rengar) grating an Evolution Point and nothing official from Riot that I have found. If you have a source as proof that it used to exist, please provide it.

Comment: @Bravo840 watch the linked video in Brian's answer

Comment: @Ender Interesting. Does anyone have another video, perhaps one taken more recently? It may have been a bug.

Comment: @Bravo840 the entire premise of the question excists on the pivoting fact that recently *this hasn't worked*. I'm asking if it was a bug, and\or if riot hotfixed this effect to no longer occur... ect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no mention by a Red it ever did, and as I don't have kha'zix and even if I did I prolly couldn't get a pentakill I can't give you a confirmed answer.

I hate to use youtube as a source but here is your [pentakill to evo point](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fH0dYUrnCuo).

The only RED confirmed way that this is accomplished is listed below.
[Rengar and Kha'zix interaction](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2608972) : If Rengar kills Kha'zix after a certain point (level 16 I think) he gets the "Head of Kha'zix" and can't lose stacks anymore from his necklace. If Kha'zix wins he gets a 4th evolutionary point letting him have all 4 evolutions.

Comment: I'm talking about the pentakill evo point, not the 'Hunt' evo point.

Comment: It may be the same thing, assuming the other team had a rengar ;)