# How does "The Hunt is On!" work if Kha'Zix and Rengar are on both teams?

Tags: league-of-legends

The answer to [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86059/what-is-the-hunt-is-on-interaction-between-rengar-and-kha-zix) question does a good job of detailing how the "The Hunt is On!" secondary quest interaction between Kha'Zix and Rengar works. However, after seeing this interaction for the first time, and then later playing a blind pick game, I started wondering:

What happens if there is more than one Kha'Zix / Rengar pair in the game?

This would only be possible in blind pick games, but you could potentially have Kha'Zix / Rengar vs Rengar / Kha'Zix. Does each pair get it's own secondary quest? Or is there just one secondary quest shared among all 4 champions?

Answer (score 3):

Rengar must kill or get an assist on and against Kha'Zix on the other team, just like Kha'Zix must kill or get an assist on and against Rengar of the other team.  You could have the whole team be Rengars or Kha'Zix, but each one would have to get a kill/assist against the other team's opposite of them. **Its per character, not global(Assuming the answer to that question is correct).**

Comment: Sick idea for a custom map! 5 Rengar vs 5 Kha`Zix. Or 5 Mundo vs 5 Cho's. Or or 5 Leona vs 5 Katerina. Or or or .. just imagine if 5 Blitzcranks are on the same team. They can just pull 1 enemy straight back to their own inhibitors if they want. Or ... 5 teemo's just shrooming every possible inch of the map... Omg Nerdgasm here.